# A problem with optimization of function that contains loops

Tags: python-3.x, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a problem with optimizing of a function that contains loops.
I start with paricular `lista=[0.002,0.006,0.003,0.02,0.008,0.006,0.05]`
of floats and the intervals `(0,k*0.0025),(0.005,k*0.005),(0.005,k*0.0125), where upper border depends. So, depending on which of the interval the float of list belong to, I assign to the function one of values k*0.005,k*0.01,k*0.025 and k*0.05 that also depend on k.

I want to minimize `k` such that the sum (new scalar function) of values of `assign(k)` or `sum(assign(k))` is equal to 0.32.

I used `scipy.optimize` procedure to do that. My constraint is `constraint=sum(assign(k))-0.32` and objective function iz `fun(k)=k`. So, I minimized `k` to satisfy the constraint.

```
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize


lista=[0.002,0.006,0.003,0.02,0.008,0.006,0.05]

def assign(k):
    return list(map(lambda x:(k*0.005 if x in np.arange(0,k*0.0025,0.001) 
    else k*0.01 if x in np.arange(0.0025,k*0.005,0.001) else k*0.025 if x in 
    np.arange(0.005,k*0.0125,0.001) else k*0.05), lista))

def constraint(k):
    return sum(assign(k))-0.32

def fun(k):
    return k

k0=0
bnds=[(0,10)]
cons={'type':'eq','fun':constraint}
res=minimize(fun,k0,bounds=bnds,method='SLSQP',constraints=cons,options={'maxiter':2000})
print(res)
```

I got *k=1.1999* which is a strange result, it does not satisfy the constraint. It should be `2` since `sum(assign(2))=0.52`.
I also got a error message:

```
  message: 'Iteration limit exceeded'
```

Does anyone knows how to overcome this limitation?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
lambda x:(k*0.005 if x in np.arange(0,k*0.0025,0.001) 
else k*0.01 if x in np.arange(0.0025,k*0.005,0.001) else k*0.025 if x in 
np.arange(0.005,k*0.0125,0.001) else k*0.05)
```

Please don't do that.
A short lambda function is fine,
but this one is long enough to deserve a name and a readable function definition:

```
def assign1(x, k):
    if x in np.arange(0, k * 0.0025, 0.001):
        return k * .01
    if x in np.arange(0.0025, k * 0.005, 0.001):
        return k * .025
    ...
```

But having taken a moment to start writing that out, it immediately appears to be wrong.

1. I cannot believe you meant `.0025`, rather than `k * .0025`, as a lower bound.
2. Suppose some random noise is added, so rather than `x` we have `x + epsilon`. Then your function returns a constant of 5% of `k`, which seems Bad.

In general, we do not expect that `int(x * 1000) == x`.
So code it using proper ranges:

```
def assign1(x, k):
    if 0 <= x < k * .0025:
        return k * .01
    if k * .0025 <= x < k * .0050:
        return k * .025
    ...
```

Supply a better constraint and I believe you will be happier
with how the optimizer converges.

EDIT

The optimization [tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) suggests that for this SLSQP method
you should be passing in both `fun` and `jac`.

Also, the `full_output=True` [exit mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html)
offers diagnostic advice about what went wrong.

Comment: J_H thank you very much for your response. I agree with you about intervals. I also was suspicious but I got the problem in this form. I must check it.

Comment: But regarding to lambda function, I think that loops within comprehensive list better fit than usual loops, but within lambda function it is even better than comprehensive list. When I say better I mean faster.

Comment: I tried in form you proposed but I got the same message.